# Passing arguments to Python script wrapped in shell script

Tags: python, shell

Consider the following Python script, **script.py**:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-a', type=int)
parser.add_argument('-b', type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

print('a + b = {}'.format(args.a + args.b))
```

And the following shell script, **runner.sh**:

```
python3 script.py
```

I know I can run **script.py** like this `$ python3 script.py -a 4 -b 6` to get the following result: `a + b = 10`, but I want to run `script.py` from within the shell script, and be able to pass `-a` and `-b`, like this: `./runner.sh -a 4 -b 6`. However, when I try this, those arguments are not passed:

```
$ ./runner.sh -a 10 -b 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 10, in <module>
    print('a + b = {}'.format(args.a + args.b))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

How can I pass arguments to a Python script that's wrapped inside a shell script? For what it's worth, I also tried `sys.argv`, to no avail.

Comment: Canyou show us runner.sh?

Comment: **runner.sh** is literally `python3 script.py` in a .sh file, as shown above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the `bash` script to pass its arguments along to `script.py`:

```
#!/bin/bash

python script.py "$@"
```

Your script was ignoring its own arguments, and running `script.py` with no arguments.